# AChartEngine set max item count

Tags: android, jfreechart, achartengine

Is there a way to set a max item count in a org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries (that automatically remove old data when a new data is added over the max item count limit)?

Like

```
 setMaximumItemCount(int)
```

in org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used linked list like this, I think this method is used in aChartEngine realtime plotting example:

```
    private static final int MAX_COUNT=9;

    private LinkedList<Integer> linkedList=new LinkedList<Integer>();

    if(linkedList.size()==MAX_COUNT){
        linkedList.removeFirst();
        linkedList.addLast(newInt);
    }
```

You should take a look into the documentation as well, as it's been a year I used aChartEngine so they should have added some efficient method for this.